# Select query in hibernate annotations in spring mvc

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Hi i am writing an spring mvc, employee application using mysql database,hibernate annotations and jsp . The database contains one table **"Empdata"** where empid is primary key.And there is a column **"team"** in **"Empdata**".I want to select employees in a specific team, example all the details of employees in **"Team1"**.Here i can perform delete and edit operations in the application. For delete opertaion i am using

> sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Resource WHERE empid=" +resource.getEmpId()).executeUpdate();

query.I know the commandline query for select is

> SELECT * FROM  EmpData ERE EMPLTEAM ="Team1"

I want to know how to convert this query into hibernate.

please help,thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

you can convert the query in the following way:

```
String sql = "select ed from EmpData ed where emplTeam = :emplTeam";

Query query = session.createQuery(sql);

query.setParameter("emplTeam ", team);

List<EmpData> empDataList = (List<EmpData>)query.list();
```

but you should have a class called EmpData containing a property emplTeam similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EmpData")
class EmpData {

    ....

    @Column(name = "EMPLTEAM")
    private String emplTeam;

    public String getEmplTeam() {
        return emplTeam;
    }

    public void setEmplTeam(String emplTeam) {
        this.emplTeam = emplTeam;
    }
}
```

(I used annotations hibernate .. but you can do it the same way using .hbm.xml files)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", "Raj");
```

In your case i guess the Entity name is Empdata(The object that represent the table)
And the field in the object is team(That has getter and setter in object)

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Empdata where team=:teamParam");
query.setParameter("teamParam", "team1");
```